# Optimize slow update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have two tables:

1) **Testone** - has 100k rows and 1 Index and 6 NON-Clustered index

2) **Testtwo**  - has 316 Million rows, 1 Index and 4 NON-Clustered index

I have update statement need to optimize the following one due to taking more time when executing this query, could you please help me the best approach..

```
update mp 
set mp.ModelInfoID = mi.ModelInfoID 
from Testone mp 
inner join Testtwo mi on mp.ModelNumberStr = replace(replace(mi.Model, '/', ''), '-', '') 
where MemberID is not null and mp.ModelInfoID is null
```

Comment: A join using the the replace (or any other) function will perform horribly! You need to join your tables on a common, indexed column. If there isn't one then your query will never perform well with millions of rows.

Comment: Perhaps add a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) to testtwo instead of the inline replace(replace.  The computed column can then be used in the index yielding SARgable results

Answer (score 0):

start with just optimizing this
look at the query plan
index on MemberID, mp.ModelInfoID, and mi.ModelInfoID will help

```
select mp.ModelInfoID, mi.ModelInfoID 
  from Testone mp 
  join Testtwo mi 
    on mp.ModelNumberStr = replace(replace(mi.Model, '/', ''), '-', '') 
   and MemberID is not null 
   and mp.ModelInfoID is null
   and mi.ModelInfoID is not null -- no need to update if they are the same
```

Cleary the replace(replace(mi.Model, '/', ''), '-', '') is going to be the bottle neck.  A computed column with an index may do the trick.